# The grass is greener on the other side (it's a matter of perspective)

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image]
What word is hidden in this image?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The hidden word is:

> [image: cubes that spell out TULIP]
>
>  That is: **TULIP**.
>
>  The image in the question shows the mesh of a cube. If you look at the assembled cube from the indicated directions, the lines in the respective colours give the image above. For this to work, the cube must be transparent or just a wireframe. The dashed lines above indicate hidden lines on the far side. (And my old eyes missed it at first, but the irises of the eyes have a coloured number in it, which tells us which letter index and which lines go with each perspective. It's a bit clearer in the close-up view.)